# why these 3 lines code are right?About *p

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int *p;
scanf("%d",&p);
printf("%d\n",p);
```

In my past understandings,the "p" is a address,but now it seems that the p is a simple variable.

I cant understand why these 3 lines code are right!!!

can you help me?

Comment: is the same value that you read from input the one that is printed later?. For me it works because you can enter a "memory address" when you read, but when you print, it will print whatever value is stored on that memory position

Comment: That is C, not C++ (well, it will compile as C++, but it is the C subset and a part of it you want to steer off from)

Comment: They compile, this doesn't mean they are right

Comment: @P0W: Even if they pass the test suite, for that matter :-D

Comment: That kind of depends on your definition of "right" in this case.  On a system where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)`, this is logically fine (albeit horrible for maintainability/readability) as long as nothing tries to dereference `p`.

Comment: A pointer *is* a variable, and as *simple* as any, since it's just a sequence of bits like the others.  It's the *use* of pointers that gets complicated, not the variable itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not right. They just *seem* to work, because you ask `scanf` to store an integer and the address where to store it is the **address of the pointer** `p`. You are basically treating the storage of the pointer itself as the storage of an integer. Likewise for `printf`, you pass the address of the pointer (which contains the integer) and ask `printf` to read it from there as... an integer. You could even change the first line to

```
float* p;
```

and it would still *seem* to work. In the end, this is a good example of why you should avoid C-style interfaces which are not type-safe.

Comment: @RayLee You're welcome. Since you are new on SO, allow me to remind you to not forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) (if you feel one of the answered was helpful enough to you).

Answer (score 4):

This will only work as long as a pointer is the same size as an integer because you are basically treating the pointer as an integer.  That is, if `int` is a 32-bit integer, and a pointer `void*` is a 32-bit address.

The way it should be written:

```
int p; // not the lack of the *
scanf("%d",&p); // this gives scanf the address of p
printf("%d\n",p); // this uses p's value
```

Which will actually use `p` as an integer instead of declaring it as a pointer and treating it like an integer.

Comment: Would also be correct to use `int *p = new int(); scanf("%d", p); printf("%d\n", *p); delete p;`.  Of course, a nightmare to manage the memory just for an int...  I think it's important to note different levels of indirection between scanf and printf.

Answer (score 1):

If I will explain through your statements, then it will be

```
int *p; //Declaration of pointer variable p, which can hold the address of integer variable
scanf("%d",&p); //Getting input, will be stored at address of pointer variable p
printf("%d\n",p); //It will display the value stored at &p
```

Comment: Correct, except for the last line. It will pass a pointer as a variadic argument where an integer is expected, giving undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The code above is not really *correct*, and it is built on top of a fair amount of assumptions and C constructs.

The first assumption is that a pointer and an `int` have the same size, which will break in most (all I know) 64bit platforms. It is then using a type unsafe interface (variadic function arguments) to pass the address of an `int*` as if it was the address of an `int`. The code inside the `scanf` will assume that it is writting to an `int` and write over the bits... but the type is not an `int*` and that bit pattern might or not make sense even in the platforms where the `sizeof(int) = sizeof(int*)`

Answer (score 1):

That code is not right at all.

Some (bad) compilers may be unable to detect the problems because both `printf` and `scanf` are variadic functions... but for example g++ would warn you that the types passed don't match with the ones specified in the format strings.